# Face detection with IR images

Tags: face-detection, haar-classifier, infrared

I am using a 160x120 pixel IR camera from FLiR (the Lepton 3.5), and I want to detect face with it so I can get temperature data from a person's face. However, I am having a hard time finding a pre-trained program for face detection in infrared images. Anyone who have any tips? If not, anyone who have successfully trained a haar cascade (or another algorithm) to detect objects/faces in IR images?

Super grateful for any help :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried normalizing your images so that they become grayscale images in the range of 0 and 255? OpenCV's `haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml` must work on the normalized IR images.